# When there are heavy traffic between I/O and memory what should it be used?

Tags: buffer, dma

I had an exam last week. And they asked a question " When there are heavy traffic between I/O and memory what should it  be used ?" buffer or direct memory access.

Answer (score 0):

Buffering is effective when the data rate is variable in time, or/and the computing system is multitasking. In this case, you can accumulate data in the buffer during intensive transmission and process it later, provided that the AVERAGE transfer rate is still significantly less than the processing speed (CPU utilization is low). When processing speed is approximately equal to the transfer rate (CPU utilization is high), buffering is not efficient and even harmful (as it takes some processor time). In this case, the only way to increase the throughput is to directly load the data into memory bypassing CPU (using DMA). Therefore, DMA usage  is the correct answer in your case.